# Bubble type chart JS doesnt render because cannot find module 'gkKU3'

Tags: javascript, chart.js, analytics

I'm studying charts in javascript with the lib [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/)

I'm doing the Step-by-Step guide in [this link](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/usage.html) and i'm having problem in rendering bubble chart type. The first one the bar type its ok to run.

I'm putting my code here:

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Chart.js example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width: 500px;"><canvas id="dimensions"></canvas></div><br/>
    <div style="width: 800px;">
        <canvas id="acquisitions"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script type="module" src="dimensions.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="acquisitions.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

api.js

```
import { CubejsApi } from "@cubejs-client/core";

const apiUrl =
  "https://heavy-lansford.gcp-us-central1.cubecloudapp.dev/cubejs-api/v1";
const cubeToken =
  "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpYXQiOjEwMDAwMDAwMDAsImV4cCI6NTAwMDAwMDAwMH0.OHZOpOBVKr-sCwn8sbZ5UFsqI3uCs6e4omT7P6WVMFw";

const cubeApi = new CubejsApi(cubeToken, { apiUrl });

export async function getAquisitionsByYear() {
  const acquisitionsByYearQuery = {
    dimensions: ["Artworks.yearAcquired"],
    measures: ["Artworks.count"],
    filters: [
      {
        member: "Artworks.yearAcquired",
        operator: "set",
      },
    ],
    order: {
      "Artworks.yearAcquired": "asc",
    },
  };

  const resultSet = await cubeApi.load(acquisitionsByYearQuery);

  return resultSet.tablePivot().map((row) => ({
    year: parseInt(row["Artworks.yearAcquired"]),
    count: parseInt(row["Artworks.count"]),
  }));
}

export async function getDimensions() {
  const dimensionsQuery = {
    dimensions: ["Artworks.widthCm", "Artworks.heightCm"],
    measures: ["Artworks.count"],
    filters: [
      {
        member: "Artworks.classification",
        operator: "equals",
        values: ["Painting"],
      },
      {
        member: "Artworks.widthCm",
        operator: "set",
      },
      {
        member: "Artworks.widthCm",
        operator: "lt",
        values: ["500"],
      },
      {
        member: "Artworks.heightCm",
        operator: "set",
      },
      {
        member: "Artworks.heightCm",
        operator: "lt",
        values: ["500"],
      },
    ],
  };

  const resultSet = await cubeApi.load(dimensionsQuery);

  return resultSet.tablePivot().map((row) => ({
    width: parseInt(row["Artworks.widthCm"]),
    height: parseInt(row["Artworks.heightCm"]),
    count: parseInt(row["Artworks.count"]),
  }));
}
```

acquisitions.js

```
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";
import { getAquisitionsByYear } from "./api";

(async function () {
  const data = await getAquisitionsByYear();

  new Chart(document.getElementById("acquisitions"), {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
      labels: data.map((row) => row.year),
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Acquisitions by year",
          data: data.map((row) => row.count),
        },
      ],
    },
  });
})();
```

---

dimensions.js <-here is implemented the bubble type

```
import Chart from "chart.js/auto";
import { getDimensions } from "./api";

(async function () {
  const data = await getDimensions();

  new Chart(document.getElementById("dimensions"), {
    type: "bubble",
    options: {
      aspectRatio: 1,
      scales: {
        x: {
          max: 500,
        },
        y: {
          max: 500,
        },
      },
    },
    data: {
      labels: data.map((x) => x.year),
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Dimensions",
          data: data.map((row) => ({
            x: row.width,
            y: row.height,
            r: row.count,
          })),
        },
      ],
    },
  });
})();
```

when i inspect the code in browser the console logs the message: In my console 'Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'gkKU3'' and i'm trying to find something in npm or even in pip and found nothing, even in google this lib is mentioned, i think there is something else wrong in my code...

i dont know if u need package.jsonand node_modules, anything is only ask and i put here

thanks everyone

Comment: I put your code in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-dan-pwc76h) and it's working fine - I just changed the import paths to match an existing sandbox I forked from; maybe you can spot some differences. I thought the funny `'gkKU3'` stuff might be an auto-generated charts.js plugin id, but you haven't got to the plugin part yet ...

Comment: Just as an aside - should your `cubeToken` be posted publicly?

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, i hadnt thought about the sandbox...
and about the token, i guess its ok because its the same token the documentation expose in guide but i will put this in a variable to hide

Comment: The sandbox helps a lot! I find your comment // Create an instance of Cube.js JavaScript Client awesome

I dont know if i did right but it worked 
const cubeApi = new CubejsApi(cubeToken, { apiUrl });

cubeApi.load().then(() => {
  this.getAquisitionsByYear();
  this.getDimensions();
});

Answer (score 0):

thanks, i did it!The sandbox  helps a lot!

I was missing this call in api.js

```
    cubeApi.load().then(() => {
    this.getAquisitionsByYear();
    this.getDimensions();
    });
```